# Comparing Neural Network Architectures

Tags: neural-networks

I wanted to compare two Neural Net architectures, with the rest of hyper-parameters the same. Now once I have trained it I see the following observations:

- One of the accuracy curves of 1st NN is much more oscillatory than the 2nd (the 2nd has similar accuracy but the oscillatory 1st one sometimes goes up in accuracy and sometimes goes done compared to the relatively smooth curve of the 2nd NN)
- The loss curve of 2nd NN is lower than the 1st NN.

What can we conclude from this? Which one is better and why?

Comment: Interesting behavior! What it means depends a lot on the details of your models used, the dataset, etc. The second network sounds more robust from your description, but it's hard to know without more details.

Comment: @SimonAlford all hyperparameters are constant except architecture. Which behavior fo you think is more favorable?

Comment: What are the architectures of each? Ignoring anything else the behavior of the second neural network sounds preferable but it's hard to put weight behind my words without knowing the details.